# Status is canceled in task without initialization with token and with ThrowIfCancellationRequested call in lambda

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I thought that the canceled status of a task is set if ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=net-6.0)):

> The task acknowledged cancellation by throwing an `OperationCanceledException` with its own `CancellationToken` while the token was in signaled state, or the task's `CancellationToken` was already signaled before the task started executing.

But if you call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` in the lambda in the task without initialization with token, then the status changes to canceled.
Is this a bug or please explain what's going on?

Tested on C# for .NET 5 on VS 2019 and .NET 6 on VS 2022.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(500);

            void MyMethod()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            }

            Task t1 = new Task(MyMethod);
            t1.Start();

            Task<int> t2 = new Task<int>(() => { MyMethod(); return 1; });
            t2.Start();

            Task t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod);

            Task t4 = Task.CompletedTask.ContinueWith((t) => { MyMethod(); });

            Task t5 = Task.Run(MyMethod);

            Task t6 = Task.Run(() =>
           {
               while (true)
               {
                   Thread.Sleep(100);
                   cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
               }
           });

            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6);
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Status t1 from new Task:                            {t1.Status}");  //Faulted
            Console.WriteLine($"Status t2 from new Task<:                           {t2.Status}");  //Faulted
            Console.WriteLine($"Status t3 from Task.Factory.StartNew:               {t3.Status}");  //Faulted
            Console.WriteLine($"Status t4 from Task.CompletedTask.ContinueWith:     {t4.Status}");  //Faulted
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine($"Status t5 from Task.Run:                            {t5.Status}");  //Faulted
            Console.WriteLine($"Status t6 from Task.Run with lambda:                {t6.Status}");  //Canceled
        }
    }
}
```

`Faulted` instead of `Canceled`.

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RyhIsX).

Output:

```
Status t1 from new Task:                        Faulted
Status t2 from new Task<int>:                   Faulted
Status t3 from Task.Factory.StartNew:           Faulted
Status t4 from Task.CompletedTask.ContinueWith: Faulted
Status t5 from Task.Run:                        Faulted
Status t6 from Task.Run with lambda:            Canceled
```

Comment: Which is the unexpected behavior? Is it that the `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4` and `t5` are `Faulted`, or that the `t6` is `Canceled`? Or you are asking for the reason about this inconsistency?

Comment: Fixed the code, added t6 to WaitAll. t6 should be Faulted instead of Canceled. None of these tasks are initialized with a token involved. They should not have a canceled status. But one task has a canceled status, although the only difference is that the initialization occurs through the Run method and the lambda, the above initialization occurs through the Run method and the method, the operations are the same. The status is different.

Comment: You might have found a bug.

Comment: Maybe. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bug in the C# compiler. Minimal reproduction:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => // Resolved to Task.Run(Action)
            {
                bool condition = true;
                if (condition) throw new OperationCanceledException();
            });
            try { await task; } catch { }
            Console.WriteLine($"if (condition): {task.Status}");
        }
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => // Resolved to Task.Run(Func<Task>)
            {
                if (true) throw new OperationCanceledException();
            });
            try { await task; } catch { }
            Console.WriteLine($"if (true): {task.Status}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
if (condition): Faulted
if (true): Canceled
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NTj0iP).

The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) has many overloads, including one with an `Action` parameter, and one with a `Func<Task>` parameter. It seems that throwing unconditionally inside a `while (true)` or `if (true)` or `for (; ; )` block in the lambda, triggers the asynchronous resolution.

The reason that the `Task.Run(Func<Task>)` overload results in a `Canceled` instead of `Faulted` task, is because the `Task.Run(Func<Task>)` [is essentially a shortcut](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) for this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<Task>(function,
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
    TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
```

When the `function` is an `async` method, it always succeeds at producing a `Task`. This task is passed to the [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap), which propagates its status as is (the `CancellationToken` is not passed to the `Unwrap`). Also `async` methods by design transition to a canceled state when they encounter an `OperationCanceledException`. The combination of these two factors results in the observed inconsistent behavior. This behavior might be an oversight and not intentional. But since the `Task.Run` is already 10 years in production, it's probably too late to change it now.